# How do we call solana methods if program.rpc deprecated?

Tags: anchor, program, javascript, idl

I initialized a correct program

```
  const provider = getProvider();
  const program = new Program(idl, programID, provider);
```

When I called this function

```
await program.rpc.create("name", "description", {
    accounts: {
      company,
      user: provider.wallet.publicKey,
      systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
    },
  });
```

I was getting this error:

> Transaction simulation…ocessing Instruction 0: custom program error:
> 0x0

I just swithced to use `program.methods.create` and it worked. So I thought this is the way how to call solana methods. Then I had another function call with `program.methods:

```
await program.methods.enter(new BN(0.1 * web3.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL), {
    accounts: {
      // public key that is passed to this function as argument
      company: publicKey,
      user: provider.wallet.publicKey,
      systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
    },
  });
```

this function never runs. this time I switched to `program.rpc.enter` and this time it worked. I do not understand what is causing this conflict.

I tried this to call `create` fn

```
await program.methods
    .create("name", "description")
    .accounts({
      company,
      user: provider.wallet.publicKey,
      systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
    })
    .rpc();
```

I still got this error

> Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed:
> Error processing Instruction 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `.rpc` to the end of `await program.methods` to send the transaction

Example format below, (`signers([])` can be excluded if there are not additional signers required):

```
// sends transaction
await program.methods
  .instructionName(instructionDataInputs)
  .accounts({})
  .signers([])
  .rpc()
```

Or you can create a transaction and then send the transaction:

```
// creates transaction
const transaction = await program.methods
  .instructionName(instructionDataInputs)
  .accounts({})
  .transaction()

await sendTransaction(transaction, connection)
```

Or you can create an instruction, and add multiple instructions to a single transaction:

```
// creates first instruction
const instructionOne = await program.methods
  .instructionOneName(instructionOneDataInputs)
  .accounts({})
  .instruction()

// creates second instruction
const instructionTwo = await program.methods
  .instructionTwoName(instructionTwoDataInputs)
  .accounts({})
  .instruction()

// add both instruction to one transaction
const transaction = new Transaction().add(instructionOne, instructionTwo)

// send transaction
await sendTransaction(transaction, connection)
```

Comment: I tried the first method but did not work. i pasted the code of how I tried.

Comment: What version of Anchor are you using? Also, could it be because you are trying to initialize an account that already exists? (assuming the `create` instruction is initializing the `company` account, which uses a PDA as the address)

Comment: "@project-serum/anchor": "^0.26.0",  anchor-lang = "0.24.2"

Comment: try making sure all the anchor versions match, also run `anchor --version` to check which version of anchor cli you're using

Comment: regarding " could it be because you are trying to initialize an account that already exists?". Everytime I call `create` contract function new account gets initialized?

Comment: what does `create` do in your program?

Comment: let me change the contract and redeploy it. then I will try to call the function the way you mentioned. If Icannot  call `create` function twice, that means I am initializing same account that already exists. If that is the case I should ask another question.

Comment: Looks like I cannot call the same function twice. i am not sure if it is related to initializng same account. I will askk a clean questiion. ty for your help